# SQLite - How to insert to table with preliminary scan of the fields?

Tags: sqlite

I use a database in my project and when i insert values ​​into a table i need to check if the field already has a value that does not produce an insert.
for exemple:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (column1) values ('some_value1')
```

if some_value1 alredy exists in column1 do not insert the value.

Comment: I think that it is possible to make a preliminary SELECT and next step it is compare it with insert value. but i think this is can make with a simple query.

Comment: Are you thinking of WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select .... ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `unique` constraint on `myTable.column1`. Then, whenever you try to insert a duplicate value, it won't let you as it violates the constraint. You can either catch and handle this error, or just let the DB engine do it's thing automatically.

EDIT: Note that SQLite doesn't allow you to do many alterations to your table, once it's created; so you may have to recreate your table with the constraint in place.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be handled using the conflict resolution IGNORE method on SQLite. The code below should do the trick. The column1 here should be set to unique for this.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO myTable (column1) values ('some_value1')
```

I'm using the following links for reference;

- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Comment: For clarity sake: there must be a specific kind of constraint violation for the IGNORE to take effect:`The ON CONFLICT clause applies to UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints ...When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the IGNORE resolution algorithm skips the one row that contains the constraint violation and continues processing subsequent rows of the SQL statement as if nothing went wrong.` So there would have to be a unique constraint as Xophmeister suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Tim, would this still work fine for the mentioned scenario if column1 is UNIQUE & NOT NULL then? (and not only UNIQUE as I suggested).

Comment: didn't mean to suggest your advice was incorrect. Violation of either the UNIQUE or the NOT NULL constraint (or of both) will be silently handled by the IGNORE. BTW, a unique INDEX in this regard is treated the same as a unique constraint.